# How do I get mouse wheel working on vim for Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, vim, mousewheel

After using VIM on Mac OS X Marvericks that has mouse scroll support set by default, and now being a Windows 8.1 user, I am trying to enable mouse wheel scroll support on Vim 7.4 for Windows running it form PowerShell, but failed to a working solution.

Considering what I have found so far, I've set in my c:\Users\.vimrc the line:

```
set mouse=a
```

So far so good, I read from some forum answer, that I had to set the following mappings:

```
map <Esc>Oa <C-Y>
map <Esc>Ob <C-E>
map <Esc>[1;2a <PageUp>
map <Esc>[1;2b <PageDown>
map! <Esc>Oa <C-X><C-Y>
map! <Esc>Ob <C-X><C-E>
map! <Esc>[1;2a <PageUp>
map! <Esc>[1;2b <PageDown>
```

I am not an advanced VIM user, just use the basics for coding, so I'd appreciate if somebody could guide me through a step by step solution.

Comment: I think this is a function of your Powershell terminal -- nothing to do with Vim. Mouse wheel works in GVim by default. Mouse wheel works when Vim is run in Powershell running Console2. Mouse wheel does not work when Vim is run in default Powershell window. Changing Vim settings isn't going to help, I am afraid.

Comment: At a guess I'm going to say that you aren't likely to be able to get this to work for console vim inside powershell. I doubt powershell reports mouse events to the console application in a way that vim can understand (I wouldn't be surprised if it doesn't report them at all). The mappings you listed are to map the escape sequences used by the terminal to report mouse events into vim actions but unless you can find powershell equivalents to those (assuming powershell has them) this isn't going to work.

Comment: @Jay It *could* help if the problem was the sequences powershell uses aren't recognized by vim but as I just said I would doubt that *that* is the problem here.

Comment: Further to my comment, you can run Powershell in Console2, and mouse wheel does work in Vim there. https://chocolatey.org/packages/Console2

Comment: @Jay I installed Chocolate and Console 2 and got PowerShell working from it but the Mouse wheel does not work, do I have to set something somewhere?